# Middle-of-the-day intoxication?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

Considering all categories, I've selected some examples of multiple winners and put them in order. However, I have a problem deciding where to put the one remaining entry on this list. Here's my ordering so far:

> 1. Small village
> 2. AlEvel
> 3. <strike>Day</strike> <strike>Daaay</strike> Daaaaay
> 4. Merlot, Pinot Noir, Syrah
> 5. Honey, sweetheart, darling
> 6. Tango, two-step & White Fang, Akela
> 7. Favourable attitude killing animals
> 8. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
> 9. Melanistic leopard

And here is the troublesome entry:

> ? Middle-of-the-day intoxication

Where should I place the remaining entry? Why do you think I have trouble deciding?

Comment: is "Merlot, Pinot Noir, Syrah" three entries or one named as shown?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton The latter. Each number 1-9 is one entry in the list.

Comment: I was relieved when I realized this was puzzling.se and not workplace.se (the symbols do look similar)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should go

> either between 1 and 2, or between 2 and 3.

We have:

> ```
>  1948 Hamlet              Small village
>  1950 All About Eve       AlEvel
>  1962 The Longest Day     Day Daaay Daaaaay
>  1981 Reds                Merlot, Pinot Noir, Syrah
>  1983 Terms of Endearment Honey, sweetheart, darling
>  1990 Dances with Wolves  Tango, two-step & White Fang, Akela
>  1997 Good Will Hunting   Favourable attitude killing animals
>  1999 The Matrix          [1 0; 0 1]
>  2018 Black Panther       Melanistic leopard
> ```

These are all

> multiple Academy Award winners

and the last one

> seems like it could be either Twelve O'Clock High, from 1949 (putting it between 1 and 2), or High Noon, from 1952 (putting it between 2 and 3).

Answer (score 8):

EDIT:  Gareth-sniped.

OK, so these are:

> Movie titles in order of release date

Small village

> Hamlet

AlEvel

> All about Eve

Day Daaay Daaaaay

> The longest Day

Merlot, Pinot Noir, Syrah

> Reds

Honey, sweetheart, darling

> Terms of Endearment

Tango, two-step & White Fang, Akela

> Dances with Wolves

Favourable attitude killing animals

> Good Will Hunting

[1001]

> The Matrix

Melanistic leopard

> Black Panther

and your choice:
Middle-of-the-day intoxication

> High Noon

should go

> Between 2 and 3 if we're going by release date

Still working on why there is confusion.

Comment: Sorry about the sniping!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No worries, I didn't even have a full solve